# How to Pass value of php to python in loop

Tags: php, python

I have two code one is working which is not in loop and another is not working which is running in loop .so please tell me how to pass multiple value of php to python.

> **Working**

**Test.php**

```
$item='example';
$tmp = exec("python C:\Users\Desktop\php_python.py ".$item."");
echo $tmp;
```

**file.py**

```
import sys
print sys.argv[1]
```

**Output**

```
 example
```

> **Not Working**

**Test.php**

```
$item='example';
$i = 0;
while ($i < 4){
    $item='example';
    $tmp = exec("python C:\Users\Desktop\php_python.py ".$item."");
    $i = $i++;
    echo $tmp;

}
```

**file.py**

```
import sys
print sys.argv[1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably missed escapeshellarg inside the exec function while calling python script

Please try with this:

> exec("python C:\Users\Desktop\php_python.py ".escapeshellarg($item)"")